# Accelerometer sensitivity

Tags: accelerometer, sensitivity

I'm working with a MEMS Accelerometer, [specifically the MS 3028](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7F3028_Accelerometer%7FA1%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_3028_Accelerometer_A1.pdf%7FCAT-EAC0002). In it, the sensitivity is given as the following:

[image]

That seems like exceptionally large variation in sensitivity. I am aware that this value varies with temperature and input voltage, but it is given that "All values are typical at +24°C, 80Hz and 5Vdc excitation unless otherwise stated", which per my understanding means a constant temperature and input voltage.

I do not understand whether there is a factor that I have missed that justifies this level of variation, or how to determine a "normal" value for my simulation of the 3028.

[image]

Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently a Wheatstone bridge in a MS 3028 accelerometer uses something called an Excitation Voltage.  Read more about it in section one of [this ti.com paper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa532/sbaa532.pdf?ts=1702281602816&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

[image]

In the [MS 3028 specification](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7F3028_Accelerometer%7FA1%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_3028_Accelerometer_A1.pdf%7FCAT-EAC0002) you linked to, several lines below the mV/g Sensitivity line you copied into the question, there is a line that specifies the excitation voltage range.  As an example, the range for a 3028 which has a range of 2g (first column of the specification) is 2 Volts to 10 Volts.

In the MS 3028 specification, there is a foot not (foot note 1) next to the Sensitivity line in the table:

> 1 Output is ratiometric to excitation voltage

[This website](https://www.tabertransducer.com/transducer-input-output/) describes this as:

> The actual output of these instruments is directly proportional, or ratiometric, to the excitation voltage. This means that if the excitation fluctuates, the output will change proportionally. As a result of this dependence on a steady excitation voltage, regulated power supplies are highly recommended.

Apparently, if the Excitation Voltage is regulated, the mV/g Sensitivity value will vary less.